# How to modify Array on React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios

In api return value like this,

```
[
    "Action",
    "Comedy",
    "Documentary",
    "Drama"
]
```

I need to modify the above array like this,

```
 const techCompanies = [
      { label: "Action", value: 1 },
      { label: "Comedy", value: 2 },
      { label: "Documentary", value: 3 },
      { label: "Drama", value: 4 }
   ];
```

I used Axios to get data,

```
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/Movie/v1.0/genre");
```

Comment: how you are getting property `value` ?

Comment: may be array index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an array so you can you use the ***.map()*** function to do that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const arr = ["Action", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama"];

arr.map((arrElement, index) => ({ label: arrElement, value: index }));
```

Comment: cannot use vale: index

Comment: because the first element is 0 or for some other reason?

Comment: no, when using `value:` error message coming `';' expected.`

Comment: I typed in your link also, this error is coming https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: var Data = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = Data.map((arrElement, index) => {
      label: arrElement, value: index
    });

console.log(map1);

Comment: yeah sorry i miss the semicolon

Comment: it's not the reason. please try your answer on the above link. this also same error

Comment: I used one this error is coming,  ```Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Comment: I fixed the example above, the problem was that you have to wrap the two {} in ()